# exact target web service error for data extension

Tags: c#

I am having a problem when trying to connect to EXACTTARGET web service and upload the data from the database to the DataExtension. That is what I have, I do have a method called `getData()` this works fine. I have bolded the line that brings back an error in the string uStatus.

Comment: oh! i didn't realize. i'm just stressed.

Comment: @S.Lott, no need for the sarcasm. Also, since there seems to be comments that has been deleted here, your reply, and @tommy's, now is missing the context. You should both consider removing the comments, in which case you should flag the question again with an appropriate comment to get my comment here removed as well.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: That's not supposed to be sarcasm.  It's supposed to be three actual questions and two suggestions.  I was hoping for an explanation of how someone could miss the all caps.  I'm curious as to what causes it and what can be done to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I needed a primary key on my data extension to match the information i was sending over.